# Reduce the Loop processing time in panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

Concept : Count number of transition between two time and add the count as column in data frame. The Start time and End is first two Column in the data frame

Sample date

```
       Time_Completed   Time_of_Fetch   Base    Number of event
        03-06-2022 14:56    03-06-2022 14:14    Q112    12
        03-06-2022 14:54    03-06-2022 14:14    Q112    11
        03-06-2022 14:51    03-06-2022 14:18    Q112    9
        03-06-2022 14:52    03-06-2022 14:21    Q112    8
        03-06-2022 15:07    03-06-2022 14:25    Q112    8
        03-06-2022 14:54    03-06-2022 14:25    Q112    7
        03-06-2022 14:50    03-06-2022 14:25    Q112    5
        03-06-2022 15:11    03-06-2022 14:27    Q112    5
        03-06-2022 15:17    03-06-2022 14:29    Q112    4
        03-06-2022 15:19    03-06-2022 14:47    Q112    3
        03-06-2022 15:18    03-06-2022 14:49    Q112    2
        03-06-2022 15:21    03-06-2022 14:54    Q112    1
        03-06-2022 15:20    03-06-2022 14:58    Q106    2
        03-06-2022 15:23    03-06-2022 14:59    Q106    1
```

Below is the code I am using to get the `Number of Count` column

```
result = []
for i in range(0, len(df)):

   result.append(df[(df['Time_of_Fetch'] >= df.iloc[i]['Time_of_Fetch']) & (df['Time_of_Fetch'] < df.iloc[i]['Time_Completed']) & (df['Base'] == df.iloc[i]['Base'])].count()['Base'])

df['Check_value'] = result
```

However this method is taking some much time to complete the calculation when processing large set of data

I have tried using `apply()` and `lambda()` to reduce the run time, still not able to reduce the runtime

below is the code that i have tired

```
df_108.assign = df_108.apply((lambda row :df_108[(df_108['Time_of_Fetch'] >= df_108['Time_of_Fetch'])
& (df_108['Time_of_Fetch'] < df_108['Time_Completed'])& (df_108['Base'] == df_108['Base'])].count()['Base']),axis = 1)
```

How this can be re-written to reduce the runtime

Comment: If you want people to answer your question, you should help them and [include the sample data as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: @suvayu I did add it as text, but it automatically got converted to Image.

Comment: @suvayu now i have added the data in text mode, now can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the internal datetime difference operation:

```
import pandas as pd

# Data
dic = {'d1': ['03-06-2022 14:56', '03-06-2022 14:54', '03-06-2022 14:51'], 
       'd2': ['03-06-2022 14:14', '03-06-2022 14:14', '03-06-2022 14:18']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data = dic)

# Datetime diference
time_format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'
df['diff'] = (pd.to_datetime(arg=df['d1'], format=time_format) - pd.to_datetime(arg=df['d2'], format=time_format))

print(df)
```

Generated Output:

```
                 d1                d2            diff
0  03-06-2022 14:56  03-06-2022 14:14 0 days 00:42:00
1  03-06-2022 14:54  03-06-2022 14:14 0 days 00:40:00
2  03-06-2022 14:51  03-06-2022 14:18 0 days 00:33:00
```

Comment: This time difference, I am looking for number of transaction happened between two time